# Does this simple js code has memory leak?

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

I have a simple html/javascript code, which will create some DOM then remove them.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Custom Plunker</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <button onclick="create()"> Create </button>
    <button onclick="clearContainer()"> Clear </button>

    <div id="container"></div>

  </body>

</html>

<script>
  function create() {
    var c = $("#container");
    for(var i = 0;i<10000; i++){
    c.append("<li>Hellosd fssd f df sdf  f f wef ewf we fwe f wef ewf wef ew few f ewf wf ewf wef </li>");
    }
  }

  function clearContainer() {
    var c = $("#container");
    c.empty();
  }
</script>
```

There will be a `Create` button and a `Clear` button. When I click on the create button, it will append 10000 `li` element to the container div, and when I click on the clear button, it will remove them.

When I try it on chrome, the chrome process has an initial memory usage about 30M, it grows to 70M after I clicking on the create button several times, and when I click on clear button, it becomes 50M. It's 20M more than initial.

Then I try it on IE8, the IE process has an initial memory usage about 30M, it grows to more than 100M after I clicking on the create button only once, and when I click on clear button, it becomes 80M. It's 50M more than initial.

Is the code has memory leak? How to fix it?

Comment: Are you somehow measuring the actual data use or are you measuring the (more likely) memory reserved, which is will be more than the data actually in use?

Comment: Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3SX59/) to see it in action.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is the code has memory leak?

No. The browsers are just keeping some of the memory they allocated in case they need to reuse it, and/or haven't (yet) garbage collected the objects that are no longer referenced. Because you've released all of your references to the list item elements (via jQuery's `empty` call), it's down to the browser to actually let them go.

Of course, this answer assumes there are no bugs in the jQuery functions you're calling causing memory leaks (in particular the one that creates the `li` elements). It's probably a reasonable assumption, although of course every once in a while even a well-respected library can have errors. If one of jQuery's common functions (that includes element construction) has a significant memory leak in a given version, it's likely to get found, reported, and fixed within a reasonable time, given the number of people using the library and the engaged team behind it.

And we're also assuming that there are no bugs in the browser's handling of the DOM manipulations causing memory leaks, which is a much less certain assumption. (Historically, browsers [regardless of the flavor] have had all sorts of issues with memory leaks; I don't think *any* browser has been immune.)

But there's no leak in *your* code, if you see what I mean.

Comment: Are you sure ? I tested OP's code and after each create/clear the taken memory was more important by about 5 to 10 MB.

Comment: @dystroy: As sure as you can be looking just at that code. The OP isn't keeping any references to the `li` elements, so the OP's code is not the cause of a memory leak. As I said, it's always possible there's one in one of the jQuery functions the OP is calling, but it's more likely just memory churn.

Comment: Firefox 19 on OS X "keeps" like 30MB after the first *create/clear* and falls back to this amount after each new round.

Comment: @insertusernamehere: There you go, if it keeps falling back to the same amount after the first pass, that shows you that you're not causing a memory leak. Firefox (which is famous for being a memory hog) probably allocates some internal structures on the first pass that it keeps around, or at least allocates some memory that's less easily identified as unreferenced and so isn't GC'd as quickly.

Answer (score 4):

By testing on Chromium/linux, I reliably reproduce your leak : each create/clear cycle makes the memory grow by 5MB to 10 MB, and this memory doesn't seem to be released.

I noted that it's possible to avoid the leak by slightly changing the clear function to replace the parent element instead of emptying it :

```
  function clearContainer() {
    var c = $("#container");
    c.remove();
    $('<ul id="container"></ul>').appendTo(document.body);
  }
```

With this code, the memory comes back to the same level after each create/clear cycle.

I don't think the problem is in jQuery, but more probably in the browser's DOM objects as Firefox doesn't seem to have the same problem.

---

**EDIT** :

By automating the tests to push it farther, I could see the memory finally decreasing (I topped about 150 MB for the tab then could come back to 70 MB). The way the memory is managed here clearly is greedy but there's no real memory leak. As the memory consumption can be so different, I'd recommend you to remove the parent element instead of clearing it but this won't prevent any crash as a memory crash seems unlikely.

Comment: +1 for the effort and the change. *"...and this memory is never released."* How long did you wait / what did you try to see that this is **never** released? Did you keep at it until something crashed? That's the gold standard of a "memory leak" (and what you would have to do, pretty much, to report it as a bug in Chromium). (I'm not saying it's not an interesting result, just that it's not necessarily a *leak*. And it's clearly not a leak in the *OP's* code.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The memory didn't change after my last test, 5 mn ago. It's still at 136 MB, while with my other clean function the memory is immediately released.

Comment: @ dystroy: Five minutes isn't "never". Again, you have to push it until something breaks to call something a leak. Otherwise, you just don't know what the GC is doing internally. GC is ***complicated***.

Comment: @ dystroy: Nice analysis, +1 again if I could. :-)